# Edit manytomany field right from Admin form for model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models like below

```
class Product(models.Model):
...

class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through=ProductQuantity)
```

In django admin I would like to change quantity not by opening new dialog, which is basically how admin behaves, instead selecting one of them if any, or type there and change values directly from that window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class ProductQuantityInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ProductQuantity

class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductQuantityInline]
```

That way, you can edit the `ProductQuantity` directly on the `Invoice` admin page, without any extra dialogs.